# listbox selections to other cells in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am facing a minor, yet bothersome issue in some VBA code (I am totally new to VBA). I created a list box that is linked to an array in one worksheet. I also created a drop down list whereas once the user clicks on a choice the array within the list box changes. To add, this list box is set up to have multi selection.

The problem I am facing is this: I want to set the list box up to where once a user clicks on each selection they choose and by hitting a "Submit" button that I also created, each choice will be populated in other specific cells in other Worksheets. Below is the screenshot:

[image: screenshot of listbox]

Below is the code that I have researched and put together and have put into the command button code area. What its currently doing is upon me hitting the run icon, its taking the first choice within the listbox and populating only that first choice into the cells that I defined, without me checking the choices within the listbox and hitting the submit button. While my vision seems to be working, I again want it to populate what is chosen by the user in the listbox:

```
Set sht = Sheets("Results")

Dim I

Dim j

Dim sht as Worksheet

Set sht = Sheets("Results")

j = 1 
For Each i In Me.ListBox21.List
    j = j + 1 
    sht.Cells(5, 1).Value = sht.Cells(5, 1).Value & Chr(10) & i
    sht.Cells(6, 1).Value = sht.Cells(6, 1).Value & Chr(10) & i
    sht.Cells(62, 1).Value = sht.Cells(62, 1).Value & Chr(10) & i
    sht.Cells(63, 1).Value = sht.Cells(63, 1).Value & Chr(10) & i
 Next i
```

I hope this appears correctly. If not let me  know and I will take a screenshot of the code. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It doesn't look like `j` is used in the code (at least this section of the code).  What is its purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in the same sheet you placed

- an ActiveX ListBox control named "ListBox21" with its "Multiselect" property set to "fmMultiSelectMulti"
- a button

then your code did exactly the opposite of what you described, i.e. it updated the "result" cells with ALL of the listbox value and not with only the first choice.

that said you must use the `Selected(i)` property of the `ListBox` object to check if its item at index "i" has been selected and than consequently update the cells using the `List(i)` property

like follows

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = Sheets("Results")

With Me.ListBox21
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            sht.Cells(5, 1).Value = sht.Cells(5, 1).Value & Chr(10) & .List(i)
            sht.Cells(6, 1).Value = sht.Cells(6, 1).Value & Chr(10) & .List(i)
            sht.Cells(62, 1).Value = sht.Cells(62, 1).Value & Chr(10) & .List(i)
            sht.Cells(63, 1).Value = sht.Cells(63, 1).Value & Chr(10) & .List(i)
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: You are forgetting about all the columns and additional values in your solution. The `List` collection as used in the question consists not only of the first (or bound) column but also of all the other columns. So, you need to copy over all rows and all columns of the ListBox.

Comment: The Q didn't mention multiple columns listbox. and the screenshot too. So I went with a single column solution. should it be a multiple columns listbox then it can be easily expanded as you did. cheers

Comment: Thank you so much everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The code gets a bit more complicated when you want to get only the selected item. While you just need to iterate the `.Selected()` collection, you are using the entire `ListBox21.List` collection to copy data over to your sheet. Since the `List` collection consists of all cells in the ListBox (all rows and all column), we'll have to iterate through the columns too. So, the resulting code becomes:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim intListItem As Integer
Dim intColumn As Integer

Set sht = Sheets("Results")

With Me.ListBox21
    For intListItem = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(intListItem) Then
            For intColumn = 0 To .ColumnCount - 1
                sht.Cells(5, 1).Value = sht.Cells(5, 1).Value & Chr(10) & .List(intListItem, intColumn)
                sht.Cells(6, 1).Value = sht.Cells(6, 1).Value & Chr(10) & .List(intListItem, intColumn)
                sht.Cells(62, 1).Value = sht.Cells(62, 1).Value & Chr(10) & .List(intListItem, intColumn)
                sht.Cells(63, 1).Value = sht.Cells(63, 1).Value & Chr(10) & .List(intListItem, intColumn)
            Next intColumn
        End If
    Next intListItem
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much everyone! The suggested codes that were posted actually worked! My issue now is that the cells are populated with with only certain choices within the set of listbox choices. For example, the set will only send two of the four choices I checked off. Is it because of the integer that is set for i? I set the command button code to look like this now:

`With Me.ListBox21`

`For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            sht.Cells(4, 4).Value = sht.Cells(4, 4).Value & Chr(10) & .List(i)
        End If
    Next i`

`For i = 1 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            sht.Cells(4, 7).Value = sht.Cells(4, 7).Value & Chr(10) & .List(i)
        End If
    Next i`

`For i = 2 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            sht.Cells(4, 10).Value = sht.Cells(4, 10).Value & Chr(10) & .List(i)
        End If
    Next i`

`For i = 3 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            sht.Cells(4, 13).Value = sht.Cells(4, 13).Value & Chr(10) & .List(i)
        End If
    Next i`

`End With`

Do I need to define the order of the listbox choices withing the listbox code? Please let me know.